# Is there a way to increase the number of characters that sys.stdin accepts on python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a program that accepts a block of text from the user using sys.stdin as the block of text may contain newline characters and regular input() ends upon detecting a newline character. However, when a particularly large paragraph is pasted into the function sys.stdin only accepts the first ~500 or so characters before failing to read the rest of the characters in the paragraph until the next newline statement like so:

```
text = str(sys.stdin.readlines())
print(text)
```

If `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.` is entered then sys.stdin only reads until "with desktop publishing" and then stops. However if the paragraph is broken up into smaller paragraphs, then it reads all of the text.

Does anyone have any ideas on if there is a way to increase this limit or to read in a large block of user text whilst not ending upon pressing enter?

Comment: There shouldn't be a limit, at least not one Python imposes. How are you running the program?

Comment: There isn't any inherent limit in Python, please provide more details about how exactly you are running this, what the platform is etc etc

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with `echo Lorem Ipsum [...] | python -c 'import sys;print(sys.stdin.readlines()[0])'`. It prints the full text, also with much larger input (~3 million characters). (Ubuntu 20.10, Python 3.8)

Comment: I'm running the program on a windows machine on visual studio code, but even if I run the program in python the input will still only accept up to "desktop publish", even if just try entering as many characters as possible manually, it still stops around 500 characters and will not let me input anything else until I press enter